# If a point equally distant of the vertices of a regular tetrahedron, does this mean it is the center of the sphere circumscribed in that tetrahedron?

Tags: spheres

If a point equally distant of the vertices of a regular tetrahedron, does this mean it is the center of the sphere circumscribed in that tetrahedron?

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Yes..................

Comment: for calculations: place the vertices at half the corners of a cube around the origin, $(1,1,1); (1,-1,-1); (-1,1,-1); (-1,-1,1)$  where the pairwise distance (edge length) is $2 \sqrt 2$  this way.

Comment: Create spheres centered around each vertex.  If the only intersection point of all 4 spheres is the center of the tetrahedron's circumsphere, then yes.